# What's an alternative to handle unknown number of tabs in a dashboard?

Tags: gui-design, tabs, dashboard

I have multiple tabs on a dashboard where it will navigate to different sections. Once it reaches the maximum number of tabs on a row it will come down to another row. The number of tabs is not defined, the user will create any number of tabs in his/her dashboard.

This looks really cluttered and unattractive and currently looking for a UX solution for this problem.

[image]

Comment: which browser do you use the most? How much time have you spent using other browsers? What's the most number of tabs you've ever had open in each? Which do you favour over the others for working with large numbers of tabs? Why?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how log you can allow user to add new tabs, and also not sure if tabs can be combined into one group like,

```
- Group 1 -> Tab1 , Tab2, Tab3
 - Group 2 -> Tab4
 - Group 3 -> Tab7, Tab8 and so on
```

Then like menu hierarchy we can give UI which would be more simpler to user to access each section.

If Not then there are more other two option that I can think of,

> 1) Layout all tabs in in single row, which would scroll horizontally

[image]

> 2) Layout tabs in left side sidebar, Here either allow user to vertically scroll all tabs

[image]

> If you help me understand feature in detail like on the run user can
>   add chip like options and and those will be added as a tabs or what
>   then i can explore more on this cz, even with the options that I can
>   think of does not give that smooth UX.

Answer (score 1):

Although the usual norm for a dashboard is to keep a viewable height, they can be made to scroll vertically as what happens in Google Analytics and a lot of other analytics pages. Instead of creating multiple tabs, it is best to try to sort multiple of them in a single long scroll page particularly useful when the same filter is applicable, makes it easier for the user to change filters and does not pop any caching issues in maintaining the filter selection for individual tabs.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

First solution is vertical scroll, often used on mobile. With placing arrows right, and when needed left.. 
 
Second solution is having "toogle more" button on end, where you toggle all other tabs that didnt fit.

Thirds solution is "mega drop down", as you maybe can think that tabs are not best solution if you have so many items.